# Python binary format exception

Tags: python, binary

Given following `Python` codes:

```
binaryE = "{0:b}".format(11749)

print binaryE

one = binaryE[0]
zero = binaryE[1]

print one

print zero

if one == 1:
   print 'equal'
else:
    print 'not equal'

if zero == 0:
    print 'equal'
else:
    print 'not equal'
```

The output from the console is:

```
10110111100101
1
0
not equal
not equal
```

Why it is not equal? By the way, what is the correct way to make a comparison with the output `binaryE[index]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are of different types:

```
print(type(one), type(1))  
# (<type 'str'>, <type 'int'>)
```

So you are comparing string to an integer. To fix this, convert the strings to int:

```
if int(one) == 1:
   print 'equal'
else:
    print 'not equal'

if int(zero) == 0:
    print 'equal'
else:
    print 'not equal'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare a string (`<class 'str'>`) to an integer (`<class 'int'>`). You need to compare objects of the same class, that is an integer compared to an integer or a string compared to a string.